# OpenCL "multithreading" example

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencl

I'm trying to multi-thread with OpenCL, but I'm getting the sense that this is incorrect terminology.

I have a simple C++ function, and I'd like to either continually send it with its parameters to the GPU or in batches.

What is a simple example of this, and what is the technical term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-thread is not an incorrect terminology. You can say porting your application on to GPU by using OpenCL.

To start with you can install AMD APP SDK and go through an OpenCL sample called Template. This sample explains step-by-step procedure to use OpenCL.
The sample can also be found at https://github.com/clockfort/amd-app-sdk-fixes/tree/master/samples/opencl/cl/app/Template

Comment: @Gracchus Just remember that you're not "sending C++ functions to the GPU". Going at it with this mentality is sure to result in disappointment, it's not as simple as just using OpenCL and getting a 25x speedup, otherwise everyone would be doing it already. You generally need to design your code around parallel execution to see the real speedups.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you Thomas!  Could you add a quick supplemental answer to explain that for +1?  Thank you so much in advance!